# Move to next page of php table without refreshing

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I'm fairly noob when it comes to php and was just wondering how I can have my table split into pages as it has over 200,000 records in the database and also if it's possible to go to the next/previous page of the table without refreshing the webpage?

Here is my table, any advise is very much appreciated!!!

```html
a<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM aliases where client_id='$userid' ORDER BY time_edit DESC";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
 echo "<table border=1>";
 echo "<tr align=center>";
 echo "<th width=25%>Alias</th>";
 echo "<th width=25%>Times Used</th>";
 echo "<th width=25%>First Used</th>";
 echo "<th width=25%>Last Used</th>";
 echo "</tr>";
 echo "<tr><td>No Results</td></tr>";
}
 echo "<table border=1>";
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<th width=25%>Alias</th>";
 echo "<th width=25%>Times Used</th>";
 echo "<th width=25%>First Used</th>";
 echo "<th width=25%>Last Used</th>";
 echo "</tr>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$timesused=$row['num_used'];
$alias=$row['alias'];
$alias=htmlentities($alias);
$firstused=$row['time_add'];
$firstused = date('d M Y H:i:s', $firstused);
$lastused=$row['time_edit'];
$lastused = date('d M Y H:i:s', $lastused);
 echo "<tr align=center>";
 echo "<td>$alias</td>";
 echo "<td>$timesused</td>";
 echo "<td>$firstused</td>";
 echo "<td>$lastused</td>";
 echo "</tr>";
}
 echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Check out the datatables plugin and use their server-side pagination.  https://www.datatables.net/

Comment: Check out this ajax pagination (http://www.sitepoint.com/pagination-jquery-ajax-php/)

Comment: Datatables or similar jsvascript plugin for sure...with json feed and server side processing option enabled for that much data

Answer (score 0):

add a class to your cells:

```
a<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM aliases where client_id='$userid' ORDER BY time_edit DESC";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table border=1>";
    echo "<tr align=center>";
    echo "<th width=25%>Alias</th>";
    echo "<th width=25%>Times Used</th>";
    echo "<th width=25%>First Used</th>";
    echo "<th width=25%>Last Used</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>No Results</td></tr>";
}
    echo "<table border=1>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th width=25%>Alias</th>";
    echo "<th width=25%>Times Used</th>";
    echo "<th width=25%>First Used</th>";
    echo "<th width=25%>Last Used</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    $countRow = 0;
    $class = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$countRow += 1;
$timesused=$row['num_used'];
$alias=$row['alias'];
$alias=htmlentities($alias);
$firstused=$row['time_add'];
$firstused = date('d M Y H:i:s', $firstused);
$lastused=$row['time_edit'];
$lastused = date('d M Y H:i:s', $lastused);
    echo "<tr align=center>";
    echo "<td class='visible".$class.">$alias</td>";
    echo "<td class='visible".$class.">$timesused</td>";
    echo "<td class='visible".$class.">$firstused</td>";
    echo "<td class='visible".$class.">$lastused</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    if($countRow == 50){ $class += 1; $countRow = 0; }
}
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

and on client side use javaScript, jQuery or what you prefer to hide or show them...

there are plugins that do it for you as commented before...
This is not the best answer but I hope it helps you.